# Count the number of times a string appears in the reverse position of the string

Tags: python, string

I am trying to figure out a way that you can count how many times a letter appears in the exact opposite position. For example:

word = 'ABXCEEVHBA' --> The correct output give me 3 because A is first and last. B is second and second from last and so forth.

I have found an answer that gives me the correct result but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this ideally with no modules.

```
word = 'ABXCEEVHBA'
reverse = ''.join(reversed(word))

sum =0
for i in range(len(word)):
    if word[i]==reverse[i]:
        sum+=1

print(int(sum/2))
```

Comment: `print(sum(word[i - 1] == word[-i] for i in range(1, len(word) // 2 + 1)))` OR `print(sum(c == word[-i] for i, c in enumerate(word[:len(word) // 2], 1)))`

Comment: If the word has an odd number of characters you'll count the middle character as matching its reverse position.

Comment: This code does quite a lot of unnecessary work -- you need only iterate over the first half of the word, and you don't need the reversed copy of the word at all.

Comment: The common theme is that you can simply compare the corresponding indexes from each end of the string, and make use of the fact that Python uses negative indexes to count from the end.

Answer (score 1):

Believe this shall do it:

```
>>> count = 0
>>> for i in range(len(word)//2):  # meet half-way.
    if word[i] == word[~i]:
        count += 1

        
>>> count
3
```

Comment: Clever approach of `~`, neat solution.

Comment: Glad that you feel it's helpful.

Comment: What does (~) do?

Comment: Try it - ~0 == -1；～1== -2⋯

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with zip by combining the string with the inverse of itself:

```
sum(a==b for a,b in zip(word,reversed(word)))//2
```